# accessing folder structure out of web directory - denied

Tags: php, apache, permissions, centos, webserver

I have a web app (PHP) which needs to access the folder structure out of the webroot.the system is deployed in a CentOS VM.
code is as follows
`dir("/home/farhath/ems/steps");`
but this give a warning as " failed to open dir: Permission denied"

in order to overcome the issue I tried following 4 options which didn't work out (still the same warning keeps on coming.)

1. giving the folder `"/home/farhath/ems/steps"` full permission (777)(though it is not recommended enabled to see if that issue is based on the permission)
2. changing the owner and the group of that folder to 'apache'- the user on which the web server runs.By
   `chown -R apache:apache /home/farhath/ems/test1`
3. Adding user 'apache' to the 'root' usergroup
4. Adding following to the httpd.conf, (to the directory)

   > php_admin_value open_basedir none

Comment: Can you do an `ls -l` for that directory and then show what it returns (*permissions/owner/etc*)

Comment: Yes I did so , and the group and the user were shown as apache : apache.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server? Is there any more info in the error log? Depending on what you're doing you may need to alter permissions for the parent directory as well.

Comment: Yes. Tried restarting many times, but didn't work out. And also the entire folder path is given  777 permission.

Comment: I did another modification, added a symlink for that folder structure to a folder in `www ` directory. `ln -s /home/farhath/ems /var/www/html/test` but even when i acces through that path still the permission is denied

Comment: the symlink worked out after applying the following command `chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/test/ems`